# List of applications using dsync or is dsync used in production?

Tags: linux, performance, disk, synchronization, device-mapper

We want to use dsync in production server, Is it production ready? I want to know the list applications using dsync. can someone provide me the list of applications which are using dsync.

Source code: https://bitbucket.org/tknauth/devicemapper/
Ref: https://daguilopez07.medium.com/bidirectional-file-sync-in-centos-7-csync2-lsyncd-fec4432ec90b
Ref: https://www.usenix.org/conference/lisa13/technical-sessions/presentation/knauth

Edit: If the dsync project is not active, Is there any other open source alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There has apparently been no development since the initial publication of dsync in 2013. Given that the project is based on version 3.2.0 of the kernel, it is not usable as-is in production.